# Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.so | Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am starting to make a LWJGL project in Eclipse, and I have gotten this error output after trying to create a window:

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
a) Add the directory that contains the shared library to -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath.
b) Add the JAR that contains the shared library to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
[LWJGL] Enable the SharedLibraryLoader debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.DebugLoader=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.so
at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:162)
at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:62)
at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:674)
at renderEngine.Display.createWindow(Display.java:20)
at gameEngine.MainLoop.main(MainLoop.java:8)
```

The jars that I have put in my library/build path are `lwjgl.jar` and `lwjgl-glfw.jar`The code in my main function is very simple:

```
package gameEngine;
import renderEngine.Display;

public class MainLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display window = new Display(1, 1, "game");
        window.createWindow();


    }

}
```

and all the code in renderEngine.Display is for testing that GLFW has initialised and a method for creating a window `createWindow()`, and is showing no errors. I searched for liblwjgl.so in my LWJGL folder that has all the jars in it, but I can't find anything called "liblwjgl", so I'm assuming that there is a jar with this file in it that I am unaware of. This is my first time using LWJGL, so I do apologise if this is an obvious fix.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue in Eclipse?

P.S if there is any information that I have left out I would be more than happy to edit it in.

Comment: Did you specify the directory that contains `liblwjgl.so` in the Java Build Path in the tab Libraries in a _Native library location_ subnode of one of the JARs?

Comment: I have not specified any such file; I have only added the 2 jars mentioned and that is all.

Comment: You have to do this to fix this issue. It is required because you do not use 100% Java code, but some Java code that delegates to one or more platform-dependent native libraries (in your case at least `liblwjgl.so`).

Comment: So how do I do that? I do not know where liblwjgl.so is located

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the directory that contains `liblwjgl.so`:

1. In ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path*** tab ***Libraries*** expand either the `lwjgl.jar` or the `lwjgl-glfw.jar` node
2. Select the ***Native library location*** sub-node and click ***Edit...***
3. In the *Native Library Folder Configuration* dialog specify the **directory that contains `liblwjgl.so`**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I did some more poking around and it turns out that I had to add ```lwjgl-natives-linux.jar``` and ```lwjgl-glfw-natives-linux.jar to the library. I might add this as its own answer.